# Swift Chart Axis ordering issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

that tracks someone's sleep into the 4 categories awake, rem, core and deep.  I have the graph almost how I want it, showing the sleep data at various times of the night (each hour), however I am lost on how I am meant to get my Y axis showing in the right order.  I want it split into four, for each of the sleep stages, starting top awake, below REM, below core, at the bottom deep, 25% of the height of the graph.  However, no matter what I try, it maintains the order core, awake, deep, REM.  I have tried using the .chartYAxis, but it didnt seem to do anything.  I can see in the documentation how to adjust this for numbers, or dates, but for what I want, I am pretty lost, especially as I get no errors, it just fails silently to order them.  I thought about somehow using an Integer to represent each of the sleep types, 0 = awake, 4 = deep, and somehow correspond those to a String value, but I am not sure how to achieve that.  Thanks for the help!

```
enum SleepType: String, Plottable, CaseIterable {
    case Awake
    case REM
    case Core
    case Deep
}

struct SingleSleep: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let startDate: Date
    let stopDate: Date
    var sleepTime: TimeInterval = 0 //in minutes
    var sleepType: SleepType
}

struct SleepExampleView: View {
    
    var sleep = [
        SingleSleep(startDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729208384), stopDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729209374), sleepTime: 16.5, sleepType: .Core),
        SingleSleep(startDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729209374), stopDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729209404), sleepTime: 16.5, sleepType: .Awake),
        SingleSleep(startDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729209404), stopDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729209794), sleepTime: 16.5, sleepType: .Core),
        SingleSleep(startDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729209794), stopDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729211234), sleepTime: 16.5, sleepType: .Deep),
        SingleSleep(startDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729211234), stopDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 729211864), sleepTime: 16.5, sleepType: .REM),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        //chart
        
        Chart {
            ForEach(sleep, id: \.self) { sleep in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Time", sleep.startDate),
                    y: .value("Type", sleep.sleepType.rawValue)
                )
            }
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(
                values: [SleepType.Awake.rawValue, SleepType.REM.rawValue, SleepType.Core.rawValue, SleepType.Deep.rawValue]
              )
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .hour, count: 1)) { value in
                AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.hour(), centered: true)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .background(.clear)
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The order is correct for me. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Hi thank you so much for trying to help me, please find edited on my original post a working example using my real sleep data from a couple of days back.  The x axis isnt showing for whatever reason in this code example but it isn't relevant to my problem so please overlook this.  The problem is specifically the Y axis showing "Core, Awake, Deep, REM", rather than "Awake, REM, Core, Deep".  The issue seems to stem from the fact the sleep types occur in that order.  I.E. my first type of sleep was core, and my second was awake, therefore it shows in that order.  But I do not want this.

Comment: Thank you. I reproduced the issue. This seems like it depends on the order of sleep types in the data.

Comment: Yes definitely agree with that.  I was hoping that my usage of .chartYAxis {AxisMarks(.values: [...])} would override that but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the y values is a problem about the *domain*, not the axis.

You can use `chartYScale` to modify the domain to whatever set of values you want:

```
Chart {
    ForEach(sleep) { sleep in
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Time", sleep.startDate),
            y: .value("Type", sleep.sleepType)
        )
    }
}
.chartYScale(domain: .automatic(dataType: SleepType.self, modifyInferredDomain: { domain in
    // put your order here:
    domain = [SleepType.Awake, .REM, .Core, .Deep]
}))
// you don't need chartYAxis here since sleep type is discrete data
// the y axis shows all the values by default
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .hour, count: 1)) { value in
        AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.hour(), centered: true)
    }
}
```

Note that I used the `SleepType` values themselves to plot the y axis, instead of their `rawValue`s. `SleepType` conforms to `Plottable` after all.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved my sanity. I can't upvote you because I am new but I hope others do as this was super helpful.

Comment: Not sure if you will see my message but one thing that seems to be a problem with doing this is that the lines do not reach the labels.  So for example the awake label is on the very of the graph, however the line graph never reaches the top to signify that the person has woken up.  Awake looks like REM because it does not actually touch the gridline.

Comment: @joeymichigan yes, this is the default with categorical data. You can *probably* customise that with axis marks. Otherwise, you’d need to use an integer type for the y axis, and use axis value labels to make them say “Awake”, “Core” etc. I’ll try to do that when I’m free, and/or you can post a new question (please look for duplicates first).

Comment: @joeymichigan `.chartYAxis { AxisMarks(preset: .aligned) }` fixes it for me. Try that.

Comment: Seems good, thanks again!